# How do I exit the code at a certain breaking point in a function

Tags: c++, function, recursion, break

*In this function to calculate the factorial of a number:*

```
int fact(int n) {
    
    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return n * fact(n - 1);
}
```

How do I add a condition

```
if(n<0)
cout <<"Error negative values are not accepted";
//Here I want to add something that makes me exit the function and stop the code after the cout statement is printed
```

Comment: From the `main` function you can just `return`. Otherwise, if you want to exit the program use [`std::exit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit). Alternatively, if it's considered an exceptional error you could *throw an exception*.

Comment: Or throw an exception.

Comment: Or return -1, since it's well outside the range of values you intend to return. You have plenty of options, so just choose one.

Comment: However, you could use other ways to avoid the problem of using negative numbers, for example by using *unsigned* integer types.

Comment: That is the subject of a new question. Please include a proper [mre] in that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `std::exit()` after the cout statement

Comment: How do I use that ?

Comment: Here a link for explanation [std::exit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit)